# How to make a hover effect change another "object" selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

For example I have two classes `A` and `B`, I need that when I hover over the change which is the amount, color, etc. B. I do not know if I can do this using CSS and `onmouseover`.

I'm putting a piece of code that handle the creation of the table and the definition of the class `C`. 
What I need here is that when the User delecione or hover over the table activate this class `C`

```
 jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
      url:urllst,
      datatype: 'json',
      height: 'auto',,
      ignoreCase: true,
      colNames:['UF','NAME','CITY' ],  
      colModel:[
         {name:"uf",index:"uf", width:100, sorttype:'text', viewable: true, frozen: true, focus: true, 
         stype:'text',
         formoptions:{elmprefix:'*', label: 'UF:', rowpos:1, colpos:1},
         editable:true,
         editrules: {required: true},
         edittype: 'custom',
         classes: 'c',
         editoptions: {style: "text-transform: uppercase",
                      'custom_element' : macro_uf_element,
                       'custom_value'   : macro_uf_value,

                        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy guys, I resolved as follows. 
I declared the function `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` because only `hover` was setting the color and not returned to normal. 
When you position the mouse over the table row selection will occur in class `C`.

```
 $("#tabDados").mouseenter(function(){
   $(".c").css("background-color","#eff3f8");
  });

 $("#tabDados").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".c").css("background-color","#fff");
  });
```

Comment: `Hover` allows for two callbacks.  You can also do `$("#tabDados").hover(callback1, callback2)`  The first callback would be the mouseenter, and the second would be the mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use javascript, but I could be wrong.

```
//grab all of the item images and make sure their popup description shows
var $contentWrapper = $("#contentWrapper");
//and bind the events that allow us to have a popup window follow the cursor
$contentWrapper.on("mouseover", className, function(event) {
    var $itemDescription = $(this).parent("").find(".description");
    //when the users cursor enters the item ensure that it enables vision of the popup and initialize the coordinates
    updatePosition(event.clientX, event.clientY, $itemDescription);
    $itemDescription.show();
});
```

that's a little snippet of code I use for showing a div when a user hovers over an image, I believe this is similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: No man, it doesn't work, i also tried, 

<style>
    .blue {background-color: blue;}
</style>

<script>
        $('#a').hover(function(){
        $('#b').toggleClass('blue'); // Change text color in B when A is without hover
        
</script>
for exemple, but and also does not work, anyway thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have? I'll do my best to help out. I can assure you the above code works, since I'm using it hehe